# Shall a pointer to an array compare equal to a pointer to its first element?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer, c++17

Imagine that I have an array `int x[10];` and in my implementation of C++ abstract machine a pointer to the array does not compare equal to a pointer to its "first" element (the result of the array-to-pointer conversion applied to `x`) but compares equal a pointer to the "last" element `x[9]`. I.e. `(void*)x == (void*)&x` is `false` and `(void*)&x[9] == (void*)&x` is `true`.

Would such  implementation be conforming? The only thing I know it "violates" is a non-normative Note in [[basic.compound]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#4):

> [Note: An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address.  — end note]

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. This is an area where C++ incorporates [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) and then extends the standard declaring the pointer to be a `prvalue` of type `"pointer to T"`. [C++ Standard 7.3.2 Array-to-pointer conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). The C++ standard explicitly states `"The result is a pointer to the first element of the array."` So how are your results different?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, the result of the array-to-pointer conversion is a pointer to the first element of the array. We could imagine it means array element with number `0` (for the purposes of the pointer arithmetic). Does this pointer have to compare equal to a pointer to the whole array? Intuitively yes, but I don't know any normative wording saying this. Or wording from which you could infer this.

Comment: It's ill-formed to make the comparison in the title.  Are you actually asking about the code `(void*)x == (void*)&x`. In that case you are comparing the results of conversions to `void *`.

Comment: @M.M [Cast to `void*` does not change a pointer value](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.ptr#2), it is still a "pointer to" the array or a "pointer to" the result of the array-to-pointer conversion. The results of cast [represents the same addresses](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#def:represents_the_address) as before the cast. Pointer equality [is defined in terms of "represents the (same) address"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.eq#2.2). In short: cast to `void*` only makes it well-formed but does not affect the result.

Comment: The [7.3.2 C++ Array Pointer Conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array) link above should be this one.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  Casts do affect the result.  Without the `void *` casts, `x == &x` is UB.  `(void*)x == (void*)&x` is well coded and _true_.

Comment: @chux it is not UB, it is ill-formed.

Comment: Okay, so you are asking that in your "What if?" implementation of C++ the results of C++ 7.3.2 was a pointer to the last element instead of the first -- "would that be conforming?" The only answer than can be given is (1) No not to the current draft of the C++ standard, but (2) Yes to your "What if?" implementation of your own. Beyond that, I'm still having difficultly understanding exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin _so you are asking that in your "What if?" implementation of C++ the results of C++ 7.3.2 was a pointer to the last element instead of the first_ No. The result of 7.3.2 is a pointer to `x[0]`. But the address of the array is the same as the address of `x[9]`.

Comment: That's where the wheels of my understanding are falling off. Somewhat of a mental mobius. If the *"address of the array is the same as the address of `x[9]`"*, that says to me the array starts at `x[9]` and the only way I can envision that is if there is a pointer to `x[9]` that is being as an array (somehow). Do you have a test case that says `int *p = array;` is actually the same as `&array[9]`? Is there somehow I can test this?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin in `int* p = array;` there is array-to-pointer conversion yielding a pointer to `x[0]`, not `x[9]`.

Comment: Okay, I give, white-flag raised. That has been the entire misunderstanding I'm obviously not smart enough to see. `&x[0]` cannot equal `&x[9]`. It just can't. So when you say *"But the address of the array is the same as the address of `x[9]`"*, I concede defeat -- and that is a rare event.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin _`&x[0]` cannot equal `&x[9]`. It just can't._ But I'm not saying it can.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: "*The result of 7.3.2 is a pointer to x[0]. But the address of the array is the same as the address of x[9].*" OK, I'll play along. If the "address of the array" is identical to the result of array-to-pointer conversion as outlined by [7.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.array) aka: [conv.array], then what you want to do is clearly contradictory. So... how do you define the "address of the array" such that [conv.array] is not involved? Show me an operation you wish to perform on `x` to yield a pointer, which will *not* invoke [conv.array].

Comment: @NicolBolas _Show me an operation you wish to perform on x to yield a pointer, which will not invoke [conv.array]_. Ehm... https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.unary.op#3

Answer (score 3):

See [basic.compound (6.9.2)]/3:

> A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to [...] an object represents the address of the first byte in memory occupied by the object.

Since `x[0]` is the first element of the array (and arrays are specified to have no initial padding), the first byte of `x` must be the same as the first byte of `x[0]`.

In [conv.ptr]/2 it says:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T ”, where T is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv void”. The pointer value (6.9.2) is unchanged by this conversion

I don't see any other way to interpret that than that the value of `(void *)&x` represents the address of the first byte of `x`  .

Comment: _Since x[0] is the first element of the array (and arrays are specified to have no initial padding), the first byte of x must be the same as the first byte of x[0]_ It is just a logical loop, not an answer. I'm asking why the first byte of `x` must be the first byte of `x[0]` and you answer "because it must". What if I store the array elements backwards and the first byte of `x` is the first byte of `x[9]`? Reversing elements does not add any padding.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer to be clear, are you suggesting that `x[9]` might be the first element in memory of the array?

Comment: If you imagine an implementation with linear address space and trying to catch me violating https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.rel#3 implemented in terms of comparing addresses as numbers — forget. I have an implementation which has very fat pointers so I can implements expr.rel very formally, not thinking about linear addresses. Yet in this imlementation a pointer to an array compare unequal to a pointer to its first element. Is this conforming&

Comment: My answer isn't a loop. The premise is that `x[0]` is the first array element and the conclusion following from that premise is that `(void *)&x == (void *)&x[0]` must be true.

Comment: Ok. Let `x[0]` be what is called the first element of the array. Then array-to-pointer conversion yield a "pointer to" `x[0]`. For me it says nothing about how it compares to `&x`.

Comment: It's ill-formed to compare `x` to `&x`. The question is about `(void *)&x == (void *)&x[0]` and therefore you must take into account the behaviour of conversion to `void *`, which my answer covers.

Comment: I've thought I explained that "pointer to" means value and not syntax. Cast to `void*` does not change the value.

Comment: So, since the case of `(void *)&x == (void *)&x[0]` is proven, and you agree that the casts did not change the values , what question remains exactly?

Comment: It is not proven. Its proof refers to itself.

Comment: No it doesn't. The premise is that `x[0]` is the first array element (which you just agreed in a comment to accept) and my answer proves that `(void *)&x == (void *)&x[0]` is true based on that premise and quotes from the standard.

Comment: You are mixing 2 things saying "the first array element". The first meaning that it is an element with index `0` for the purposes of pointer arithmetic. The second one — that it occupies the initial piece of the array storage. But the only way you can check the second fact is by comparing the pointers. And you are trying to prove that comparison is `true` using the fact which defined in terms of this comparison. This is the loop in your proof.

Comment: By "first array element" I mean that it occupies the initial piece of the array storage.  Are you saying now that you do not concede that `x[0]` denotes an `int` subobject occupying the initial piece of the array storage?

Comment: Exactly. I think [conv.array], when it says  "the first element", means "array element with subscript `0`". And you can check that implementation gives you a pointer to this element when you perform the a-to-p conversion: array initialization is defined in terms of matching array subscripts with initializing expressions in initializer list. But these parts of the standard tell you nothing about the address of the first element.

Comment: Obviously if `x[0]` denotes `int *` then `x[9]` can be the beginning address of an array, IFF `x` is `int (*x)[b]` (equivalent to conversion from `int x[a][b];`)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I doubt the authors of the standard considered that someone might contemplate storing array elements in a different order to their indices , so trying to read too much into their choice of wording "the first element" is unwarranted

Comment: If I understand correctly, you propose that when [dcl.array]/1 says "the array has `N`
elements numbered `0` to `N-1`", the order of the array elements in memory might not be the same as the order of their indices

Comment: @M.M Pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of array element subsripts. Relational operators are defined in terms of array element subsripts. Why should I think about something more than the array element with subsript `0` when I read "the first element of the array"?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer if we're getting into "why would" -- why would anyone number the array elements in an order other than 0, 1, 2, 3, ... ?

Comment: @M.M you have to number them in this order. But there is only Note saying that the element with index `0` occupies the first byte of its enclosing array's storage.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Notes are intended to clarify the meaning of the other text; if the note says something that you can't prove from the normative text then it might indicate the normative text doesn't clearly reflect the authors' intent, i.e. the normative text is slightly defective.   "Non-normative" is not the same as "should be ignored" -- otherwise why even include them in the document at all?

Comment: @M.M _if the note says something that you can't prove from the normative text then it might indicate the normative text doesn't clearly reflect the authors' intent, i.e. the normative text is slightly defective_ 100% agree. I want to check if there really no normative text proving that Note or I couldn't find it.